# Handlers in for-loop Services

Tags: android, service, handler, android-logcat

I used the following code in Activity class, it was working fine.K was updated accordingly. But when I used it in service class, the variable k in for-loop is not waiting for handler.

```
    for( k=0;k<personsToSend.length;k++) {
                Log.e(TAG,"outside k = "+k);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e(TAG,"Inside k = "+k);
                    }
                }, 1000);
    }
```

Logcat:

```
outside  k = 0
outside k = 1
outside  k = 2
outside k = 3
outside k = 4
Inside k = 5
Inside k = 5
Inside k = 5
Inside k = 5
Inside k = 5
```

If I try to access array by index inside handler, it gives error ArrayOutOfBoundException. Is there any solution for this or I have to use JobSheduler or something else.

Comment: `I used the following code in Activity class, it was working fine` are you sure you are using exactly the same code? Looks like it will behave exactly same in the activity

Comment: you are right. I wrote this code couple of months ago. I used the same technique, it didn't give me error(i m not sure why). But now it act same as you are saying

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Its not that great approach to put random delay. It will cause various debugging issues anf also could introduce issues in real time

Comment: Mesasage casting application. It will send sms each 100 or 10 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Runnable for that. As Following.

```
int k = 0;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

First time use

```
mHandler.post(runnable);

Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e(TAG,"outside k = "+k);
        if (k == personsToSend.length) {

        }else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
        }
        k++;
    }
};
```